# ImageButton setImageResource crashing app

Tags: java, android, onclick, imagebutton

So I've got a small problem which is doing my head in. I do know that the solution is something obvious and simple, but I'm new to programming and can't seem to get my head around it.

Basically, I've been following a Flashlight tutorial using Android Studio. In the tutorial, they used a simple button that would toggle into Flashlight ON, and Flashlight OFF modes.

I did not want to use just a button, and instead wanted to use an `ImageButton` instead, taking up the entire screen, and the clicking of the image would turn on the flashlight and change the image.

So, I simply modified the code after the flash would turn on into a `setImageResource` change. But clicking the image crashes the app rightaway unfortunately :(

Hope someone can help a noob out! Below is my Main Java file.

---

```
        package com.dbz.flash;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.hardware.Camera;
        import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.ImageButton;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            private boolean isFlashOn = false;
            private Camera camera;
            private ImageButton btnSwitch;

            @Override
            protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();

                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.release();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
                Context context = this;
                PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();


                if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                    Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your device doesn't have camera!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return;
                }

                camera = Camera.open();
                final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

                btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        if (isFlashOn) {
                            Log.i("info", "torch is turned off!");
                            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                            camera.setParameters(p);
                            isFlashOn = false;
                            //button.setText("Torch-ON");
                            btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        } else {
                            Log.i("info", "torch is turned on!");
                            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                            camera.setParameters(p);
                            isFlashOn = true;
                            //button.setText("Torch-OFF");
                            btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        `
```

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: what do you see in logcat?